# Hilbert space and Parallelogram law

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ C_\infty$ be inner product space of all real sequences $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n$  finite number of nonzero terms and the inner product defined by

$$\langle x,y\rangle =\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_ny_n$$

I want to prove this is not a Hilbert space but I do not know how to apply Parallelogram law here.

So any help appreciated

Comment: I changed $C_{00}$ to $C_\infty$, {$x_n$} to $\{x_n\}$, $<x,y>$ to $\langle x,y\rangle$, and the now-displayed equality to a displayed (rather than inline) equality. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an inner product space and accordingly it satisfies the parallelogram law.  Hence you cannot show that it is not a Hilbert space be showing it fails to satisfy the parallelogram law.

The reason it is not a Hilbert space is that it is not complete: there are some Cauchy sequences in it that fail to converge.  For example, consider the sequence whose $n$th term is
$$
(1,\ 1/2,\ 1/3,\ 1/4,\ \ldots,\ 1/n,\ 0,\ 0,\ 0,\ 0,\ \ldots).
$$
There is no element of this space to which this converges.  (I leave it as an excercise to show that it is a Cauchy sequence, but if you ask about that I might say more.)

Comment: how can I prove this sequence does not converge?thanks in advance @MichaelHardy

Comment: First show that the function that maps the sequence to its $n$th component is continuous.  Use that to conclude that the $n$th component of the limiting vector would have to be $1/n$.  Then show (this part is easy) that there is no vector in this space whose $n$th component is $1/n$ for _every_ $n$. ${}\qquad{}$